# Is String part of the core Java language?

Tags: java, string

Is the `String` class part of the core java language?

My teacher said I am only allowed to use the `String` class for my assignment if it is part of the core language that I am using.

Since I am using Java, is using the `String` class allowed?

Comment: Yes it is. It is a pre-defined class in Java class library

Comment: For future reference, there's a hint in the package (`java.lang.String`)

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

The `String` class is mentioned in the Java Language Specification (JLS), which is the document that defines the Java language.

It is mentioned in [JLS § 4.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.3).

---

<sup>*The term 'core language' is not a term which has an established definition in Java.*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's a class-based Type, not a primitive as
char or int